# Singleton Class 's copyWithZone function causing leaking problem

Tags: iphone

I detect a memory leakage of [NSCFString copyWithZone:]   I did a project search there's only one place using the copyWithZone function that's in the singletonclass.

This macro is widely used. How should I correct that?

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(classname) \
 \
static classname *shared##classname = nil; \
 \
+ (classname *)shared##classname \
{ \
    @synchronized(self) \
    { \
        if (shared##classname == nil) \
        { \
            shared##classname = [[self alloc] init]; \
        } \
    } \
     \
    return shared##classname; \
} \
 \
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone \
{ \
    @synchronized(self) \
    { \
        if (shared##classname == nil) \
        { \
            shared##classname = [super allocWithZone:zone]; \
            return shared##classname; \
        } \
    } \
     \
    return nil; \
} \
 \
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone \
{ \
    return self; \
} \
 \
```

Comment: The leak was on NSCFString, which is a private subclass of NSString. Your macro probably has nothing to do with it. `copyWithZone:` is automatically called whenever you call `copy`, so you should search your project for somewhere where you copy a NSString (or NSMutableString) without releasing an old string.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment says, the `copyWithZone` part is a bit of a red herring.

Look for where you use NSStrings, specifically where you copy them, for example this is a memory leak

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;


...


self.title = [textView.title retain]  // Over retained (and wont show up on the static analyzer)
self.title = @"B";
```